# Export a Eclipse RCP product from command Line

Tags: maven, ant, eclipse-rcp

I tried different way to export it but i couldn't succeed in it.

I need a way to export my product file which is located in my workspace.

Comment: Maven + Tycho is the recommended way to build an Eclipse RCP - see [here](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html) This provides a command line build process.

Comment: Thank you Greg. Can you please share some sample configuration with example as it's bit complex structure to me and can't figure out from where to start.

Comment: This is far too broad for an answer. You need to go through the entire tutorial very carefully.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to implement do that using command lines, you must compile the product using maven with tycho. You will need to implement every module as a artifact in Maven.

After the configuration you only need to run:

```
mvn clean install
```

Please read this link:
https://www.eclipse.org/tycho/

Here is the tutorial to configure your project:
https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html